# Large database load using rootBundle.load() blocking UI

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a large Database in asset Folder (approx 130mb). But when I am using rootBundle.load() then UI is blocking for 3-4 sec. Any solution?

code:

```
  Future<Database> initDb() async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = join(databasesPath, "hadith_db.db");

    bool fileExists = File(path).existsSync();
    if (!fileExists) {
      // Should happen only the first time you launch your application
      print("Creating new copy from asset");

      // Copy from asset
      print("starting root bundle");
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "hadith_db.db"));
      print("starting buffer");
      List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      print("finished buffer");
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    }

    // open the database
    Database db = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: true);

    return db;
  }
```

Note: For showing this data I'm using FutureBuilder

Comment: Did you try calling initDB without await?

Comment: no. I used await.

Comment: Try without using it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dart isolates. Dart isolates are used for concurrent programming, and create workers which are similar to threads but they don't share memory, they only work by message passing.
For more info, see: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html

Comment: I used isolate but code stuck in rootBundle.load() (line 54). https://codeshare.io/G8MmZv

Answer (score 0):

add pubspec.yamal file

assets:
- assets/hadith_db.db

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).